# Lebesgue measurabality of second derivative

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ have continuous derivative then if $f''$ (if there are) is it necessarily Lebesgue measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $g_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions that converges pointwise to $g$, then $g$ is measurable.

Since $f'$ is continuous, it is measurable. Let $g_n(x) = \frac{f'(x+\frac{1}{n})-f'(x)}{\frac{1}{n}}$, then $f''(x) = \lim_n g(x)$ and each $g_n$ is measurable. hence $f''$ is measurable.

Comment: This shows more precisely that $f''$ is not only Lebesgue measurable, but in fact of first Baire class (a pointwise limit of continuous functions), in particular $f''$ is Borel measurable.